# How to open VLC in a new window instance?

Tags: windows-7, windows, vlc-media-player

I always used to open a new VLC window; go to "open file"...etcetera when I wanted to watch something because when I click on a file in Windows Explorer and chose "open with" or just clicked on the file or right-clicked to choose "play with VLC" it always opened in an old already used VLC window.  Is there any way to get VLC to use a new one without always resorting to: Open VLC, "open file", find file etcetera?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Go to `Tools` > `Preferences`.
2. Make sure that `Allow only one instance` under `Instances` is **unchecked**.
3. Choose `All` at the bottom-left corner, under "Show Settings".
4. Make sure that `Allow only one running instance` under "Performance options" is **unchecked**.
5. Make sure that `One instance when started from file` under "Performance options" is **unchecked**.

[image: Instruction 2]
[image: Instructions 4 and 5]

Comment: This answer shows how to allow multiple instances, but it doesn't show how to open a second instance... can someone advise how to open a second instance of VLC?

Comment: @L.D.James once you unchecked those checkboxes, just open two video files. By double-clicking on them, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
vlc.exe --no-one-instance
```

Reference: *[VLC command-line help](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help)*

Answer (score 4):

There either have been an update or my answer is Linux-specific:

[image]

You get to Preferences: "*Tool* → *Preferences*"

Then you uncheck:

- Allow only one instance
- Use only one instance when started from file manager.

The next video you open will be in its own new instance.