# Multiple VLC instances

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

how do I configure VLC 2.0.4 to open each file I open in a new instance, meaning not the already opened window (if it is opened) and by that repalcing the currently played file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/454926/how-do-i-get-vlc-to-open-up-a-newly-clicked-file-in-a-n-e-w-instance-of-vlc-and?rq=1)

```
1. Go to Tools > Preferences.
2. Make sure that Allow only one instance under 
   Instances is unchecked.
3. Choose All at the bottom-left corner,
   under "Show Settings".
4. Make sure that Allow only one running instance under
   "Performance options" is unchecked.
5. Make sure that One instance when started from file
   under "Performance options" is unchecked.
```

[image]